# I am facing issue with chaining .populate() method in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, promise, mongoose-populate

This is my user Schema where I have addresses as array

```
 name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    require: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true,
    required: "Email address is required"
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: [6, "Password must be atlest 6 characters length"]
  },
  mobile: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
    default: "gravatar.png"
  },
  addresses: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Address"
    }
  ],
  cart: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Cart"
    }
  ],
  orderHistory: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "OrderHistory"
    }
  ]
});
```

This is post request to /user/address route where I want to create a new Address, link the user collection and address collection and populate the user collection. But it is giving me an error
"TypeError: Address.create(...).then(...).populate is not a function". I also used exec() method. I think I am not using populate and exec method correctly.

```
router.post("/address", function(req, res) {
  console.log("form data: ", req.body);
  Address.create(req.body)

    .then(function(newAddr) {
      // console.log(newAddr);
      return User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.session.user._id },
        { $push: { addresses: newAddr._id } },
        { new: true }
      );
    })
     .populate("addresses")
    // .exec((err, updatedUser) => {
    //   if (err) {
    //     res.send(err);
    //   } else {
    //     console.log(updatedUser);
    //     res.redirect("/user");
    //   }
    // });
    .then(function(updatedUser) {
      res.redirect("/user");
    })

    .catch(err => {
      res.send(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: have you solved the problem?

Comment: Yes. I used async await and it did the job. Do you know any other way to do it?

Comment: I am having the same error using async await return await this
            .populate({path:'type', select: 'title en'})
            .populate({path: 'allergiesArray', select: 'title en'}).
            exec()

Can you post your solution please?